# Regarding placement new in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator, placement-new

I am having a problem with the placement new operator. I have two programs: Program1 (operator.cpp) and Program2 (main.cpp):

Program1: operator.cpp

```
void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    void *p;
    cout << "From normal new" << endl;
    p=malloc(size);
    return p;
}
void *operator new(size_t size, int *p) throw()
{
    cout << "From placement new" << endl;
    return p;
}
```

Here is the second program to which the first is linked:
main.cpp:

```
#include <new>
int main()
{
    int *ptr=new int;
    int *ptr1=new(ptr) int(10);
}
```

I am individually compiling operator.cpp and main.cpp as shown:

```
operator.cpp: g++ -g -c -o operator operator.cpp
```

Then linking it with main.cpp:

```
g++ -g -o target operator main.cpp.
```

Surprisingly, when I am executing "./target" it is printing: "From normal new". The expected output is:

> From normal new
> From placement new

However, if the placement new and the main are put in the same file itself, then the output is as expected:

> From normal new, From placement new.

Answer (score 4):

In your [main.cpp] you're including `<new>`, which declares the function

```
void* operator new( size_t size, void* p) throw()
```

You don't declare your own function.

Hence the function declared by `new` is the only one that's known, and the one that's called.

By the way, note that C++98 §18.4.1.3/1 prohibits replacement of the function shown above (plus three others, namely single object and array forms of `new` and `delete` with `void*` placement argument).

Also, while I'm on the "by the way" commenting, chances are that whatever placement new is thought to be the solution of, there is probably a safer and just as efficient and more clear higher level solution.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't agree with you. It prohibits to overload the actual placement new: void*operator new(size_t size, void* p). But we can overload void* to int* and can overload it. I tried it in a single file and it worked. It is showing "From placement new". Then why on linking, the same thing to another file, it is not?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Re the "I don't agree", maybe you're misinterpreting "the function shown above". Re question at the end, because your function isn't declared in [main.cpp]. Just declare it. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @kingsmart: because when you have them in separate files, you're NOT overloading, as there's no overloaded declaration in main.cpp

Comment: @kingsmart: I can't declare it in main.cpp, the program and my problem is as such. I am with a tool to catch memory leaks, and all the overloadings should happen separately, that's why it is declared separately in other file. Tell me, then how does Overloading normal new operator works in separate file and giving result fine?

Comment: @Alf.P: If your idea is that, as i am overloading in separate file, that is why it is not working, then that should also happen for the other normal new operator. Then how does that work fine, on another file? I want some solution to make it to work from other file only. Plesae if you can suggest some solution.

Comment: @Alf.P: Just giving a hint of my work, and why i can't declare it in main. I am working on a memory leak tool. Idea is, main.cpp is the user program to be tested for catching leaks. When main.cpp has a new, it should go and hit operator.cpp's new where i will be putting some counters and hash tables to track that memory. Same should happen for placement, since placement new does not have memory allocation, so when the memory is used by placement new, that should also be added to the hash table. And that can happen only if we overload the placement new. Thanks kingsmasher1

Comment: @kingsmasher1: the "normal" new operator is a special case, in order to support global replacement of C++ allocation. for placement new, however, you need a declaration that is visible at each call site. you would most naturally place that in a header file, but, consider whether placement new is really necessary: it's so extremely unusual that most likely it's not necessary.

Comment: @Alf.P: How can we place it in header file Alf? Assume GDB as an example, can we tell the user, that if you have a function called "foo()" in your code, you add this "someheader.h" to your code? The end user should be able to use the tool as a black box, just linking to my tool, and invoking it and seeing the leak logs. So if you can please come up with some idea, it will really really be helpful for me.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 you may create your own version of "new" header file and instruct the user to add include path to your "black box" headers. In this new "new" file you may include the original "new" (#include_next may help) and all additional declarations needed

Comment: @user396672: Yes, at last i think we have to do that. Unfortunately, it shows how paralysed this C++ is :-(