# Using malloc/free with classes

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have some code that allocates memory for classes using malloc/realloc and then deletes them again using free. Below is an extract from what I'm working with:

```
    void NewSubInstances()
  // Invoked by each worker thread to grow the subinstance array and
  // initialize each new subinstance using a particular method defined
  // by the subclass.
{
    if (slavetotalspace  >= totalobj)  { return; }
    //Remember current large size
    G4int originaltotalspace = slavetotalspace;
    //Increase its size by some value (purely arbitrary)
    slavetotalspace = totalobj + 512;
    //Now re-allocate new space
    offset = (T *) realloc(offset, slavetotalspace * sizeof(T));
    if (offset == 0)
    {
        G4Exception("G4VUPLSplitter::NewSubInstances()",
                    "OutOfMemory", FatalException, "Cannot malloc space!");
        return;
    }
    //The newly created objects need to be initialized
    for (G4int i = originaltotalspace; i < slavetotalspace; i++)
    {
        offset[i].initialize();
    }
}

void FreeSlave()
  // Invoked by all threads to free the subinstance array.
{
  if (!offset)  { return; }
  free( offset);
  offset = 0;
}
```

I know that malloc will not call the constructor of the class, but this is dealt with by the initialize function. My question is: how can I deal with the freeing of the memory in a way that will also call the destructor of the classes (the classes generally have dynamically allocated memory and will need to delete it)?

Thanks!

Comment: In C you do not have classes and in C++ you should not be using `malloc`/`free`. Which are you trying to write and why are you doing it like this?

Comment: You did not say why you can't use new and delete which call constructor/destructor automatically. Is there some reason for that ?

Comment: Even if you have a 'raw byte array' (eg, a `char*`), which leads you (a probably 'pure C' programmer) to use  `*alloc`, you can use `new` and `delete`. Just a long shot, but you can use a `std::vector<T>` to represent your `offset`.

Comment: I haven't seen a C++ compiler with `malloc` and `free` but not `new` and `delete`. Replace malloc and free with new and delete to make your life much easier. You can still call your `init method`.

Comment: Call the destructor of the class explicitly and then free the memory using free.

Comment: IF you need to do this... which the only circumstance I can think that would make this desirable would be extreme memory pressure. Then I would HIGHLY suggest writing a custom [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) than you can use with standard container types. That will call [placement `new` for you](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and call the destructors when you're done. You can just mark your allocator as having the requirement that it's shared between all instances of the containers using it and allocate all your memory at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regarding placement new in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688401/regarding-placement-new-in-c)

Comment: @Dabo The reason I can't use new and delete is because I inherited this code from other people (it's a chunk out of a piece of software called Geant4, used for Monte-Carlo simulation in physics). I have no idea why the code uses *alloc, could it being multithreaded via pthreads have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Theolodus : no, it cannot have anything to do with it.

Comment: @Theolodus, it sounds to me like the reason for usage of *alloc (in the code you inherited) was ignorance on the part of the original developer (or code dating since before rules against such things were first pronounced). How old is the code?

Comment: @utnapistim The particular bit of code I posted was last touched in 2009. Ignorance of the rules is very likely given that thie entire code has been developed by physicists, not programmers.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I deal with the freeing of the memory in a way that will also call the destructor of the classes (the classes generally have dynamically allocated memory and will need to delete it)?

The answer to your question looks like this:

```
void FreeSlave()
{
    if (!offset)
    { return; }
    // call destructors explicitly
    for(G4int index = 0; index < slavetotalspace; ++index)
        offset[index].~T();
    free( offset);
    offset = 0;
}
```

That said, DO NOT use malloc/realloc/free in C++ (no, not even if *any excuse goes here*). While it will probably work (not sure on this), this code is obscure/has non-obvious dependencies, is brittle, difficult to understand, and it violates the principle of least surprise.

Also, please do not call your pointer "offset" and do not use C-style casts in C++ (it's bad practice).

Comment: According to provided code, `offset` is already of type `T*`, and the pointer owns an array of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use :

```
void FreeSlave()
{
    if (!offset) { return; }
    for (G4int i = slavetotalspace; i != 0; --i) {
        offset[i - 1].~T();
    }
    free(offset);
    offset = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a `destroy()` method ... since you have already `initialize()` ... the way of calling the destructor, albeit that is allowed, is really ugly and feels like a hack (which is).